# operations on sortedMap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have to implement the method `maxPricePerProductType` which returns the max price of the bids for product type, the products are alphabetically-sorted. Products whithout bids are not considered. The prototype of the method is:

```
public SortedMap<String, Integer> maxPricePerProductType() { //use toMap

    return null;
}
```

My classes are

```
public class GroupHandling {
    private Map<String, Group> groups = new HashMap<>();

    public SortedMap<String, Integer> maxPricePerProductType() { //use toMap

         return null;
      }
}

public class Group {
    private String name;
    String productType;
    Map<String, Bid> bids = new HashMap<>();

    public String getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }
}
public class Bid {
    String name;
    Group g;
    int price;

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getProductType(){
        return g.productType;
    }
}
```

Each group is interested in buying a certain type of product, and in the map `bids` are registered the options that the group have to buy products. For example the `Group G1` wants to buy smartphones and they have 3 bids: B1, B2 and B3. B1 costs 10, B2 15 and B3 7. G2 wants to buy smartphones too. It has 2 bids. B4 costs 5 and B5 costs 20. So I have to take B1, B2, B3, B4 and B5 (since they are all bids for the same product type) and add to the sorted map B5 as key and 20 as value. In short, I need to take the bids from each group, group them by type of product and add the one with the highest price to a sorted map.
This is what I tried to do:

```
public SortedMap<String, Integer> maxPricePerProductType() { //use toMap
    return groups.values().stream().
            flatMap(g -> g.bids.values().stream())
            .
             ;
}
```

But I don't know how to continue or if this part is right.

Comment: This is a little unclear. What are the strings in the map? Groups? (G1, G2, etc.) Bids? (B1, B2, etc.) How do you know that bids are from the same group, or for the same product? Is it just the initial letter? You say, "Products without bids are not considered." Are they absent from the map entirely, or represented as strings that map to null, or zero?

Comment: What should be the key of the map? Product type or bid name? I'm asking because you say that it should be the name of the bid, but then how would you know to which product type that bid belongs?

Comment: @DavidConrad unfortunately the text of the exercise is a bit unclear. However I think that product types are strictly connected to groups so for example, if there is  just a group that wants to buy shoes, and it hasn't got any bids, it means that I must not consider shoes and they are absent from the map. The key of the map is bid's name, as I written below, and the value is bid's price

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sort of misleading what `private Map<String, Gruppo> groups = new HashMap<>();` and `Map<String, Bid> bids = new HashMap<>();` hold. If the keys in these maps are `B1, B2...` and `G1, G2...` - the actual names, than you don't really need them - since that information is present in each of them anyway. So these should really be `List`s.

If there is something else, you could use:

```
 SortedMap<String, Integer> result = groups
            .values()
            .stream()
            .filter(g -> g.getBids() != null || !g.getBids().isEmpty())
            .flatMap(g -> g.getBids().values().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(b -> b.getGroup().getProductType(),
                    TreeMap::new,
                    Collectors.mapping(Bid::getPrice,
                            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()), Optional::get))));
```